# how many ways can you write a number n as a sum of 1s, 2s and 3s

Tags: combinatorics

Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ how many ways can one write $n=a+2b+3c$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$.

I have an idea as if I use a a 3-tuple to represent $(a,b,c)$, I can list all of them using two functions $f((a,b,c)) = (a-2,b+1,c)$ and $g((a,b,c)) = (a-1,b-1,c+1)$. Which makes a nice pattern that should be easy to compute for any n however I'm struggling finding an actual equation that works everytime. Right now I have one that works sometimes being; Let $x = \left \lfloor{n/2}\right \rfloor  $, $y = \left \lfloor{n/6}\right \rfloor  $ and $z = x-y$. Then the function $f(n)$ is the count.
$f(n) = 1+x+(c/2)(c+1)+bc-b(b+1)$. However I know it's wrong.

EDIT:
Sorry forgot to add that f(n) should be a function of just n.

Comment: What do you know about generating functions?

Comment: Not an extensive amount, always just managed to figure it out.

Comment: and to kingW6, taking the first few terms $f(1) = 1, f(2)= 2, f(3)= 3$ we see that $f(4) = f(3) + 2f(2) + 3f(1) = 3 + 4 + 3 = 10$ but $f(4) = 4$

Comment: A previous effort i had $f(n) = 1 + \left \lfloor{n/2}\right \rfloor +  \left \lfloor{n/3}\right \rfloor + f(n-5)$ where $f(n) = 0$ for $n \leq 0$

Answer (score 0):

$f(n)$ satisfies the recurrence
$$
f(n) = f(n-1)+f(n-2)-f(n-4)-f(n-5)+f(n-6)\tag{$n\ge 1$}
$$
This can be proven using the principle of inclusion exclusion, similarly to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3181340/recurrence-relation-of-partioning-n-into-exactly-3-parts/3181364#3181364). Let $E^n$ be the set of triples $(a,b,c)$ for which $a+2b+3c=n$, so $f(n)=|E^n|$. Furthermore, let

- $E^n_1=\{(a,b,c)\in E^n\mid a\ge 1\}$
- $E^n_2=\{(a,b,c)\in E^n\mid b\ge 1\}$
- $E^n_3=\{(a,b,c)\in E^n\mid c\ge 1\}$

Using the principle of inclusion exclusion, you can show for any $n\ge 1$ that
$$
|E^n|=|E^n_1|+|E^n_2|+|E^n_3|-|E^n_1\cap E^n_2|-|E^n_1\cap E^n_3|-|E^n_2\cap E^n_3|+|E^n_1\cap E^n_2\cap E^n_3|
$$
Furthermore, you can show $|E^n_1|=|E^{n-1}|$, via the bijection $(a,b,c)\mapsto (a-1,b,c)$, and $|E^n_1\cap E^n_2|=E^{n-3}$ via $(a-1,b-2,c)$. Using similar bijections, you get the recurrence advertised above.

Anyways, solving the above linear recurrence after determining the base cases yields
$$
f(n)= \frac1{72}(6n^2+36n+9(-1)^n+16\cos(2\pi n/3) + 47)
$$
I got this from [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a(n)+%3D+a(n-1)%2Ba(n-2)-a(n-4)-a(n-5)%2Ba(n-6),+a(0)+%3D+1,+a(1)+%3D+1,+a(2)+%3D+2,+a(3)+%3D+3,+a(4)+%3D+4,+a(5)+%3D+5).

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(n)$ be the number of ways of making $n$ as a sum of only $1$s, $g(n)$ be the number of ways of making $n$ as a sum of only $1$s and $2$s, and $h(n)$ be the number of ways of making $n$ as a sum of only $1$s, $2$s, and $3$s.

It should be obvious that $f(n) = 1$.

$g(0) = f(0) = 1$ and $g(1) = f(1) = 1$, since there will not be any $2$s for these small numbers.  For $n \ge 2$, $g(n) = f(n) + g(n - 2) = 1 + g(n-2)$.

For $n \lt 3$, $h(n) = g(n)$.  For $n \ge 3$, $h(n) = g(n) + h(n-3)$.

$$
h(n) - h(n-3) = g(n)\\
g(n) - g(n-2) = 1\\
h(n) - h(n-3) - (h(n-2) - h(n-5)) = 1\\
h(n) - h(n-2) - h(n-3) + h(n-5) = 1\\
h(n-1) - h(n-3) - h(n-4) + h(n-6) = 1\\
h(n) - h(n-1) - h(n-2) - h(n-3) + h(n-3) + h(n-4) + h(n-5) - h(n-6) = 1 - 1 = 0\\
h(n) = h(n-1) + h(n-2) - h(n-4) - h(n-5) + h(n-6)\\
$$

So now we've got a linear recurrence. For the Fibonacci linear recurrence, $F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)$, which has a related polynomial of $x^2 - x - 1$, and that polynomial has roots  $\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$, and the closed form of the Fibonacci series is based on a linear combination of exponentials of those roots, $Fib(n) = k_1 \left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n + k_2\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$.

So the polynomial associated with the $h(n)$ recurrence is $x^6 - x^5 - x^4 + x^2 + x - 1$.  That factors to $ (x  + \frac12 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)(x + \frac12 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i) (x - 1)^3 (x + 1)$  That translates into a closed form expression of the form $(k_1 + k_2 n + k_3 n^2)(1)^n + k_4(-1)^n + k_5(-\frac12 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)^n + k_6(-\frac12 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)^n$.